# Read hidden control value in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the a hidden controls in my page and assign value to the hidden control using javascript. Now i want to get the hidden control value in code behind. It always return the null value. Please help me to solve it.

```
My partial code is here.

<asp:HiddenField ID="Hfproductid" runat="server" />

 var hfproductid = document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>');
 prod_id=100;
 hfproductid .innerHTML = prod_id;


In My Code Behind
------------------
 string invid = HfInvoices.Value; //invid =""; always
```

Comment: If you change the value with javascript you have to post back the information to the server, if not you are not going to see the changes in the "code behind"

Answer (score 4):

You must set the `value` of hidden field, not `innerHTML`.

```
hfproductid.value = prod_id;
```

Comment: @user2176150 Check your page source to check that hidden field is generated or not. Maybe your codebehind make it `Visible="False"`.

Comment: Try to use if(!IsPostback)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly set value by

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
   document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>').value = "100";
 }
```

Then show the value by

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>').value)
```

Comment: What is document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>').value = "100" supposed to do on the server?

Answer (score 1):

It is beacause your page is posting back.

Thats why on clientside you may get its value through javascript but on serverside, page is posting back.

Try to use `IsPostback` Property.

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
```

**Refer:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: @user2176150 post your method where you are checking the hidden-field's value.. so that we can suggest you  the wight answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 var hdnvalue= document.getElementById('<%= HiddenValue1.ClientID  %>');
     myvalue=5;
 hdnvalue.val(myvalue);alert(hdnvalue.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
var hfproductid = document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>');
 prod_id=100;
 hfproductid .val(prod_id);
alert(hfproductid .val());
```

Hope this will work for you

Updated:

Then on post back your page is being refreshed:

Add

```
if(!IsPostback){
String test = Hdftest.value;
}
```

Try this

Comment: Hidden field value assigned successfully. But in c# page i can't read this value.

Answer (score 0):

what  juanreyesv mentioned earlier is absolutly correct,**If you change the value with javascript you have to post back the information to the server, if not you are not going to see the changes in the "code behind"**

For that you have to force tha postback event in clientside itself by using

```
 __doPostBack();
```

So your code will be,

```
var hfproductid = document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>');
                var prod_id = 100;
                hfproductid.value = prod_id;
               __doPostBack();
```

And then in Page ispostback you will get the desired value

```
if(IsPostback){
string invid = Hfproductid.Value;
}
```

The above code will work fine but since it is a forced postback without any condition it will get fired continuously so to avoid that you have to take 1 hidden field and use it as a flag to check if there is any value then dont fire the

```
_doPostBack()
```

So your final code should look like

```
 if (document.getElementById('<%= hdncheck.ClientID  %>').value == "Y") {
                var hfproductid = document.getElementById('<%= Hfproductid.ClientID  %>');
                var prod_id = 100;
                hfproductid.value = prod_id;
                document.getElementById('<%= hdncheck.ClientID  %>').value = "N";
                __doPostBack();

            }
```

In server side

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                hdncheck.Value = "Y";
            }
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                string invid = Hfproductid.Value;
            }
```